# SurfaceView on Android 2.3.6 doesn't render full region

Tags: android, android-ndk, surfaceview, surfaceholder, nexus-s

In my app I create `SurfaceView` and use it from NDK using ANativeWindow API: `ANativeWindow_lock` and then `ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost`.

The size of the surface is set by `ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry` to 320x480. The screen size is bigger - 480x800.

The SurfaceView is stretched using LayoutParams to almost full screen.

The problem that I see is that my frames are refreshed only in the region of 320x480.

[image: screenshot]

The other part of the surface is refreshed only if there is another view being animated on top or if I explicitly call `postInvalidate` on the surface view. However, `postInvalidate` works with delay.

This happens only on Nexus S with 2.3.6 with ROM from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images (2.3.6 (GRK39F)). The same device with 4.0.4 doesn't have this bug.

Works fine on Samsung Ace-2 with 2.3.6. Also works perfectly on higher versions of android.

Has anyone seen such bug? Pretty sure it is a bug on that particular phone. Any suggestions how to work around this?

Comment: I wouldn't really focus on Android 2.3.6 anymore. It only accounts for around 6% of all Android devices:https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html.

Comment: For my app statistics is a bit different. I still have 24% of users on 2.3.6. However, not sure how many of them have Nexus S.

Comment: Alright, I was just giving you a heads up incase this was newer project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of debugging and reading source code of SurfaceView I found solution. Apparently, `ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry` is not enough and the size should be also set from java. This helped me:

`public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  holder.setFixedSize(BuildConfig.VIDEO_WIDTH, BuildConfig.VIDEO_HEIGHT);
}`

Comment: The output of `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` is often helpful in these situations. The graphics arch doc goes through an example with the hardware composer summary -- https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#composition